# How can I list the info for an array of /dev/disks using bash expansion or substitution?

Tags: bash, command-line, osx, command-substitution, brace-expansion

I want the output of:

```
diskutil list; diskutil info [multiple devices]
```

Without having to do:

`diskutil info disk0; diskutil info disk0s1; diskutil info disk1` ...etc

For example, with many builtin commands like `touch` `rm` `mkdir`, etc. I can use bracket expansion to perform commands on multiple versions of a file:

```
mkdir njboot0{1,2,3}
```

Or, when searching, I can use special characters to specify matching specific patterns in a string, like:

```
find ~/ -type f \( -name *mp3 -or -name *mp4 \)
```

But:

```
diskutil info disk{0,0s1,1,1s1}    #syntax error

diskutil info /dev/*               #syntax error

(diskutil info disk$'')$'0|1|2'    #syntax error

diskutil info disk\(0,s0\)         #syntax error
```

etc...

```
diskutil info disk${disk}'0'$'s1'  #okay, getting somewhere. this works at least.
```

1. How do I perform the `diskutil` command mentioned above on multiple disks correctly?
2. Is there any **general** syntax I can follow for expansion/substitution?

---

As requested, this is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            999.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Comment: `diskutil` seems not to be available for at least my distro. What exactly is the output of `diskutil list`?

Comment: It's tagged OSX.

Comment: @slm Useful tagging. How unexpected...

Comment: @HaukeLaging - yes, it is a pleasant surprise when it's encountered 8-)

Comment: @HaukeLaging thanks for reply. sorry, `diskutil` was a poor choice. second q still applies to bash syntax in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brace expansion you're asking about will only expand for files/directories that match on disk to the pattern you use. The other issue you'll run into is `diskutil` may not be able to handle more than 1 argument at a time. To expand these you'd need to do a `while` or `for` loop, and pass the results to `diskutil` as you iterate through the loop.

#### Example

```
$ for i in /dev/*; do diskutil "$i";done
```

As to your 2nd question there isn't really any method where brace expansion can help you in situations where there are no corresponding files/directories on disk.

#### Parsing diskutil

Given the output from this command you'll have to resort to using a tool such as `awk`, `sed`, or `grep` to "parse" this output so that you can get meaningful information about the disks, for further queries calling `diskutil` a 2nd time.

#### Example

Here's a rough cut of parsing the output from `diskutil` using `grep` and `sed`. There are more efficient ways to do this but this shows you the general approach.

```
$ diskutil list | grep -E "[ ]+[0-9]+:.*disk[0-9]+" | sed 's/.*\(disk.*\)/\1/'
disk0
disk0s1
disk0s2
disk0s3
```

With this approach you can then modify the `for` loop above like so:

```
$ for i in $(diskutil list | grep -E "[ ]+[0-9]+:.*disk[0-9]+" | \
    sed 's/.*\(disk.*\)/\1/'); do diskutil info $i; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If the output of `diskutil list` is something like `disk0 disk0s1 disk1 disk1s1` (separated by space or newline) then you need something like this:

```
for dev in $(diskutil list); do
  diskutil info "$dev"
done
```

**find**

```
find ~/ -type f \( -name '*mp3' -or -name '*mp4' \)
```

You must quote the metacharacters which `find` shall see.